# How To Change BorderWidth of Checkbox in Material UI v5

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, jss

Can anybody help to change checkbox borderwidth in Material UI v5.Currently I do have custom checkbox, I want to remove borderWidth of Checkbox. I tried a lot of solutions but didn't work.

**checkbox**

```
 <Checkbox
     defaultChecked
     size="small"
     checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.checkedIcon)} />}
     icon={<span className={classes.icon} />}
 />
```

***styles***

```
 icon: {
      borderRadius: 6,
      width: 24,
      height: 24,
      borderWidth: 25,
      boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(16,22,26,.2), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(16,22,26,.1)',
      backgroundColor: '#f5f8fa',
    },
    checkedIcon: {
      borderWidth: 20,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(180deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.1),hsla(0,0%,100%,0))',
      '&:before': {
        display: 'block',
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        backgroundImage:
          "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath" +
          " fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M12 5c-.28 0-.53.11-.71.29L7 9.59l-2.29-2.3a1.003 " +
          "1.003 0 00-1.42 1.42l3 3c.18.18.43.29.71.29s.53-.11.71-.29l5-5A1.003 1.003 0 0012 5z' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E\")",
        content: '""',
      },
      'input:hover ~ &': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
        borderWidth: 20,
      },
},
```

Comment: Can't you pass a `style` prop and then do something like `borderLeft: "20px solid", borderRight: "20px solid"`?

Comment: I tried in to pass borderWith property directly in browser. But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Material checkbox work with icon, you can pass icon for **checked** and **unchecked**, here is an example,

```
<Checkbox icon={<FavoriteBorder />} checkedIcon={<Favorite />} name="checkedH" />
```

Comment: This is the right answer when you need absolute control over the checkbox svg - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-checkbox/#icon

Answer (score 0):

Just add stroke and strokeWidth in your checkbox styles it will reduce borderWidth :

```
 stroke: "#ffffff",  stroke-width: 1
```